# How to format a DateTime object to a String with the letter h, like 13h45, using the DateFormat class?

Tags: date, dart

It would be something like `DateFormat('hh:mm').format(date)`, but with the letter `h` instead of the colon. `DateFormat('hhhmm').format(date)` obviously doesn't work, as `h` is a meaningful character in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`DateFormat` documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html):

> The following characters are available in explicit patterns:
>
> ```
> Symbol   Meaning                Presentation       Example
> ------   -------                ------------       -------
> ...
> '        escape for text        (Delimiter)        'Date='
> ```

So you could use `DateFormat("hh'h'").format(date)`.

That said, you usually would use a notation such as `13h45` to represent *durations*.  If that's the case, using a `Duration` object instead of a `DateTime` object to store it would be much more appropriate and would be less misleading.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that detail about escaping characters. Personally, I read `13h45` as a date by default. A duration would be `13h45min`.